# Phalcon tutorial error PhalconException: TestController handler class cannot be loaded

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phalcon

I'm having some trouble getting `Phalcon` Tutorial 1 to work. In the end I've cloned the version of it on`Github` to make sure I'm not missing something; still getting the same behavior from that.

Pointing the browser to localhost/test as shown in the tutorial gives: `

```
"PhalconException: TestController handler class cannot be loaded".
```

Going to `localhost/test.php`, however, loads the "Hello!" test message correctly.

Phalcon is shown in `phpinfo() and get_loaded_extensions()`.

I get this behaviour even having cloned the tutorial from

https://github.com/phalcon/tutorial .

My guess is that `apache` is not re-writing URLs correctly, as described at **[Phalconphp routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605809/phalconphp-routes-not-working)** , but my problem doesn't seem to the same as the one there.

Contents of htaccess files:

```
#/tutorial/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and

```
#/tutorial/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace in bootstrap file `index.php`

```
$url->setBaseUri('/tutorial/');
```

with

```
$url->setBaseUri('/');
```

Comment: I did this but still, the problem is not fixing for me what else could be possible.?

Answer (score 3):

My bad, this isn't an error. The Phalcon tutorial seems to expect that the tutorial is being completed in a directory called /test/, not web root. It doesn't specify this, so I assumed /test would produce the behaviour shown in the tutorial with the project in web root.

Answer (score 3):

You need change Dir of Controllers and Models if u run localhost/test.php

```
try {
//Register an autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(array(
    'app/controllers/',
    'app/models/'
))->register();

//Create a DI
$di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

//Setup the view component
$di->set('view', function(){
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir('app/views/');
    return $view;
});

//Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});

//Handle the request
$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```