# PhalconException: NameController handler class cannot be loaded

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Tried with the question but it didn't fix my issue. : [Phalcon tutorial error PhalconException: TestController handler class cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918648/phalcon-tutorial-error-phalconexception-testcontroller-handler-class-cannot-be)

My application is in AWS ubuntu 14.0 and some pages are working fine but for few pages, I'm getting this error:

> PhalconException: NameController handler class cannot be loaded.

**My controller names are CamelCase!**

```
//Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});
```

I changed my **apache2.conf** file to AllowOverride : **all**:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My App is here  **projectname/admin/app/**:

```
try {
    //Register an autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        '../app/controllers/',
        '../app/models/',
        '../app/plugins/',
    ))->register();
```

cant able to debug this can anyone help what else could be the issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller page is not present in controllers then this issue will come, so plz recheck the controller page exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error so i fixed it in **public/index.php**

- Find the line  `echo $application->handle($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])->getContent()` or  `echo $application->handle()->getContent()` or code related to this.
- The main error is **request_uri** which is redirected to wrong controller
- for example if you try to echo `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, it will also show the domain name.
- so i fixed it locally like this. Replace this whole line with following code

> ```
>  $request_uri=str_replace(["\n","\r","\t"], '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
>             if($request_uri=='localhost'){
>                 $url=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
>                 array_shift($url);
>                 array_shift($url);
>                 $url=implode('/',$url);
>                 $url='/'.$url;
>             }
>             else
>                 $url=$request_uri;
>         echo $application->handle($url)->getContent();
> ```

**OR**  Simply use `/{controller name}/{function name}` in `handle` function

- The main error was that it was redirecting to domain named controller because of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but we have to ignore domain name and redirect it to controller name.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that such controller doesn't exists, like class isn't loaded.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your time. I really appreciate your answer. Are you familiar with phalcon framework.? I'm a bit new to this can u suggest some links where I can grab much knowledge on this.

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2 and use official forum https://forum.phalconphp.com